# java.io.EOFException when reading weka trained model file

Tags: java, weka, eofexception

I'm trying to load my weka trained model file to generate a prediction. But I get a error of java.io.eofexception when trying to do this. I'm sure this is got to do with my model file being not correctly formed. But I have used weka tool to create the model file and don't understand what's wrong.

Code

```
public Classifier loadModel() throws Exception {
    this.readConfFile();
    Classifier classifier;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            prop.getProperty("Output_Model_Dir") + "/best3.model");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    Log.write.info("Load Classifier Successfully => "
            + prop.getProperty("Output_Model_Dir") + "/best3.model");
    classifier = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(ois);
    Log.write.info("1");
    ois.close();
    Log.write.fine("Read Classifier Successfully");
    return classifier;
}
```

Log

```
INFO: Load Classifier Successfully => C:/Users/CRY$TAL/workspace/flysafews/system_files/best.model
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:285)
    at flysafe.predict.support.FileHandler.loadModel(FileHandler.java:104)
    at flysafe.predict.core.PredictionManager.predict(PredictionManager.java:189)
    at flysafe.webservice.WebServiceHandler.predictQuery(WebServiceHandler.java:62)
```

PS: I have used a different model file to this. when using that file, code works except for the error of arff structure being different.

Comment: @wero   49kb . The one that works is only 36kb

Comment: the problem is that the ObjectInputStream can't even read the stream header which consists of four bytes only. An access problem? What happens if you do `fis.read()` four times? Does it also return -1 meaning EOF reached?

Comment: sorry it's somewhat unclear to me. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: it shows 'first byte 172'

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `ObjectInputStream` to [weka.core.SerializationHelper.read](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/SerializationHelper.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) which expects only a `InputStream` and which wraps that `ObjectInputStream` in another `ObjectInputStream` which then fails.

Therefore simply pass your `FileInputStream fis` to `SerializationHelper.read`:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(...);            
classifier = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(fis);
```

Comment: Then I get this error.
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ED000573

Comment: @CraZyDroiD do you still create your own `ObjectInputStream ois  = new ObjectInputStream(fis)`?